# Can I Mute a Specific Sound Effect in MacOS?

Tags: macos, big-sur, system-settings, finder

In MacOS Big Sur (and previous versions) there's a sound effect when you move a file.

Is it possible to mute or change just that one sound effect without affecting the others?

Comment: I would ***strongly*** recommend against doing this (manipulating core system files never strikes me as a good idea), but one option (per [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/dp4nb1/how_do_i_change_the_file_copying_sound_in_osx/)) would be to disable SIP and replace `/System/Library/Components/CoreAudio.component/Contents/SharedSupport/SystemSounds/system/Volume Mount.aif` with a silent AIFF file (and then re-enable SIP!). Short of that, I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Did they change the sound effect with Big Sur?  I don't remember it being so annoying previously.